# How to take numbers from a string and put them into an arrayList

Tags: java, parsing

I have a program that I am trying to take a set of numbers from a string separated by commas and place them into an `ArrayList`; however, I'm not quite sure how to do it. So far what I have done is turn the String into an array of chars and then convert the chars into ints by using:

```
Character.digit(temp[i], 10)
```

This example is in a for loop iterating over a string. Let's say in this case `"1,2,3,4"`. taking the first element of the new char array and converting it to a int.

My issue is,

- A: there has to be a better way of doing this.
- B: what happens if you get a 2 or three digit number instead, e.g, `"34,2,3,65,125"`.  these will be stored as separate elements of the array when i need it to be one element.
- C: what happens if the number is a negative one, and what if that negative number is 2 or three digits long? E.g., `"-123,45,3,4,-6"`.

Remember that this is mean to be for any `String` argument.

There are lots of conditions here and I'm not sure how to solve them.

Comment: Is this a homework? Please tag appropriately if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just do:

```
String input = "-12,23,123123";
String[] numbers = input.split(",");
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String number : numbers){
    result.add(Integer.parseInt(number));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider using

- `String.split()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html
- `Integer.parseInt()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Regarding "any String argument," you have a choice: either fail on the strings which are not comma-separated numbers or redefine the task. Here comes the essence of the programming: you need to define everything. The easiest way (and the safest, usually) is to fail whenever you see something unexpected. Java will do it for you in this case, so enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function to break your String in different strings, based on the separator:

```
    String input="-123,45,3,4,-6";
    String[] vals=input.split(",");

    List<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>(vals.length);
    for(String val:vals) {
        numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(val));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First split the input `String` using `String.split()`. Then try `Integer.parseInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String testStr = "123,456,789";
String tokens[] = testStr.split(",");

ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
{     
   try
   {
      Integer num = new Integer(tokens[i]);
      numList.add(num);
   } 
   catch(NumberFormatException e)
   {  
       //handle exception
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String input="-123,45,3,4,-6, a";
String[] vals=input.split(",");

List<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>(vals.length);
for(String val:vals) {
    try {
        int a = Integer.valueOf(val);
        numbers.add(a);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Use this code. By using it you can also avoid non-integer values if there any.

Comment: If U Don't catch the exception then Ur loop is not going to iterate throughout the array-list.

Comment: Good practice is to catch only what you know; catching `NumberFormatException` is fine and as expected. Catching `Exception`  is a bad practice and should be discouraged.

Comment: I have designed this code in general. Its on user that which exception have 2 catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use StringTokenizer to split the string into substrings, and then use Integer.parseInt to convert them into integers.